# Compare Words Foreach Data (OpenCart)

Tags: php, foreach, compare, words, letters

How do you compare/check the product data of `foreach`?

I am trying to make it display a message if the data of `foreach` product warehouse in the shopping cart is different to each other.

If all the letters/warehouse are the same ignore, else output a message telling them the warehouses is different.

There may be a quicker way. I would just like to display a message to the customer to tell them they are purchasing from separate warehouses, so somehow need to compare the data to each other.

We have three warehouses. A, B and C.

Example
Customer has three products all from Warehouse A
A A A
Result = Purchasing from same warehouse. Ignore. Same if they was all from WarehouseC, WarehouseB etc.

Customer has four products from All three warehouses.
A C C B
Result = Output a message and tell them they are ordering from three separate warehouses.

How do you compare foreach data?

[image]